# How to merge/combine all rows to 1?

Tags: pandas

**This is my script:**

```py
import pandas as pd

wbSheets = pd.ExcelFile("Jaaroverzichten Cashflow.xlsx").sheet_names
frames = []

for st in wbSheets:
    df = pd.read_excel("Jaaroverzichten cashflow.xlsx",st)
    frames.append(df.loc[df["Onderdelen"].str.lower().str.contains('cash flows') & df["Onderdelen"].str.lower().str.contains('investing activities')])

res = pd.concat(frames)
res2 = res.columns[1:]



res.to_csv('Test.csv', index=False)
```

The result is in image below:
[image]

How to combine all the rows?

How to create one row "Net Cash flow from investing cash flows".
And move the values to the first row.
[image]

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
dfs = pd.concat(
    pd.read_excel("Jaaroverzichten Cashflow.xlsx", sheet_name=None), ignore_index=True
)

m = dfs["Onderdelen"].str.contains("cash flows|investing activities", case=False)
dfs.loc[m, "Onderdelen"] = "Net Cash flow from investing cash flows"

res = dfs.loc[m].groupby("Onderdelen", as_index=False).first()

res.to_csv("Test.csv", index=False)
```